# How To Remove Skype Call Tool From Browsers? Specifically Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, skype

If you view my page below:

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/nue/

... In Google Chrome (Specifically, maybe others as well?).

You will notice that there is some Skype Extension that allows users to do a Click-And-Call from the Browser. Which is messing up my design pretty bad...

How do I come across getting rid of this feature/function?

Is there some JavaScript? jQuery? HTML?

Thank you so much!
Aaron

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the problem.  It will seem to be an issue only for users who actually have that extension installed.

Comment: would this question be better asked (and answered) on [su] ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following jQuery Extension will return whether skype extension is installed or not. if it is installed you can remove the wraped link placed plain text.

```
jQuery.extend({
    skype : function(failureFunction) {
        var $ = jQuery;

        if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {
            return true;
        } else if ($.browser.msie) {
            try {
                if (new ActiveXObject("Skype.Detection")) return true;
            } catch(e) { }
        } else {
            if (typeof(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-skype"]) == "object") {
                return true;
            }
        }
        $('a[href^="skype:"]').click(function() {
            failureFunction();
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is putting this meta into the   section of the page/s.

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Tools -> Extensions" and uncheck the "Enable" box beside the "Skype Links" extension

Comment: My question was asking if there is a code that will rid of this feature, and or disable via JavaScript, jQuery, or HTML see my question.

Answer (score 1):

How can you be sure that users browsing your site won't have this plugin installed? You'll need to handle this possibility in your code, so that your page does not break.

Comment: My question was asking if there is a code that will rid of this feature, and or disable via JavaScript, jQuery, or HTML see my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to your Add-ons or Extensions and just get them disabled and you won't be disturbed anymore

Comment: My question was asking if there is a code that will rid of this feature, and or disable via JavaScript, jQuery, or HTML see my question.